# Fetch top record from query result for all databases

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have the following code.
What i need to do is when i fetch the records from the database, i need only the top record for my next procedure.
I have tried using LIMIT, TOP etc but that is not compatible with all databases.
Any help in this case is appreciated.
Below is the query

```
SELECT a,b,c,d,COUNT(*) AS cnt_next
FROM table
WHERE emp_cd='ASDF1234' and a < '01/08/2017'
GROUP BY a,b,c,d
ORDER BY b
DESC
```

Comment: Without some level of abstraction, you're setting yourself an almost impossible task. I doubt your current query is valid in ANY RDBMS!

Comment: There are many differences between RDBMS flavours and they are all being developed at different paces by different manufacturers with different agendas. Writing generic sql code that will work across all RDBMS is pretty much impossible.

Answer (score 0):

In sql server 2012 you use "OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY" . Not sure if this will help but worth  a shot!

Comment: I'm currently using 2 databases. This method will work only on one

Answer (score 0):

There are many differences between RDBMS, so it's impossible for one query that be compatible with all databases.
If you're using Mysql and Postgresql, this query could work on these 2 RDBMS.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT a,b,c,d,COUNT(*) AS cnt_next
FROM table
WHERE emp_cd='ASDF1234' and a < '01/08/2017'
GROUP BY a,b,c,d
ORDER BY b DESC) data
LIMIT 1
```

For other RDBMSs, you could find more information at this [link](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/59.cfm)